# could not find phpSerial class

Tags: php, arduino-uno, serial-communication

I have to send a number to my Arduino using the COM port using PHP. I included phpSerial class to do that. Included the PhpSerial.php containing the class phpSerial class to the PHP code. I am getting an error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'phpSerial' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\kprientvaegan\ref\com.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\kprientvaegan\ref\com.php on line 4.

Could anyone please help me to fix this?

```
   <?php
       include 'PhpSerial.php';
       $serial = new phpSerial;
       $serial ->deviceSet("COM1"); //Port number
       $serial ->confbaudRate(9600);
       $serial ->confParity("none");
       $serial ->confCharacterLength(8);
       $serial ->confStopBits(1);
       $serial ->confFlowControl("none");
       $serial ->deviceOpen();
       $serial ->sendMessage('1');
       $serial ->deviceClose();

   ?>
```

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'phpSerial' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\kprientvaegan\ref\com.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\kprientvaegan\ref\com.php on line 4.
```

Comment: Can you show whats in `PhpSerial.php` ?

Comment: If you're using the `PhpSerial` class from [phpclasses.org](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html), note that PHP is case sensitive and the class name is `PhpSerial` (with an uppercase "P")

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thank you this solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use **pyserial** module with **python**. It is very easy and powerful.

> You can to download this module from here:

[pyserial module link](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/)

> And this is the documentation:

[pyserial documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/)